# What is this function doing in Python involving urllib2 and BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, urllib2

So I asked a question earlier about retrieving high scores form an html page and another user gave me the following code to help. I am new to python and beautifulsoup so I'm trying to go through some other codes piece by piece. I understand most of it but I dont get what this piece of code is and what its function is:

```
    def parse_string(el):
       text = ''.join(el.findAll(text=True))
       return text.strip()
```

Here is the entire code:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import sys

URL = "http://hiscore.runescape.com/hiscorepersonal.ws?user1=" + sys.argv[1]

# Grab page html, create BeatifulSoup object
html = urlopen(URL).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

# Grab the <table id="mini_player"> element
scores = soup.find('table', {'id':'mini_player'})

# Get a list of all the <tr>s in the table, skip the header row
rows = scores.findAll('tr')[1:]

# Helper function to return concatenation of all character data in an element
def parse_string(el):
   text = ''.join(el.findAll(text=True))
   return text.strip()

for row in rows:

   # Get all the text from the <td>s
   data = map(parse_string, row.findAll('td'))

   # Skip the first td, which is an image
   data = data[1:]

   # Do something with the data...
   print data
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`el.findAll(text=True)` returns all the text contained within an element and its sub-elements.  By text I mean everything not inside a tag; so in `<b>hello</b>` then "hello" would be the text but `<b>` and `</b>` would not.

That function therefore joins together all text found beneath the given element and strips whitespace off from the front and back.

Here's a link to the `findAll` documentation: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#arg-text

Comment: why is there a '' with nothing in it to open the text = ? and what do the commands join and strip do exactly? And why did this have to be defined as a function before it was applied to data? Thanks.

Comment: ''.join means join each item with an empty string (so there's no delimiter).

Comment: What is its purpose then if ''.join('hello world') = 'hello world'

Comment: The purpose is to join *sequences* of strings into a single string: so ''.join(["hel", "low", "ord"]) gives "helloworld", for example.